# Nested ng-repeat drag and drop, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a native dragdrop solution for AngularJS, that can handle drag an dropping between nested ng-repeats?

What the current html looks like:

```
<section ng-repeat="list in lists">
   {{ list.name }}
   <article ng-repeat="user in list.users">
     {{ user.name }}
   </article>
</section>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I can move users to other lists.

I don't wanna have to add jQuery UI as a dependency for just dragdropping.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and wanted to use native HTML5, too. Since I couldn't find anything I eventually had to build my own library, check out the results:

http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested

Answer (score 1):

There is no native drag and drop in Angular, but look this awesome directive

http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

Check the examples, i hope thouse will helps you

Answer (score 0):

[Angular-NestedSortable](http://ngmodules.org/modules/Angular-NestedSortable) is really usefull for this case.